# Accessing properties set at runtime using property ${} notation in Mule flow

Tags: java, ant, properties, mule, mule-el

In a Mule flow, I have a property set in my flow as follows:

```
    <set-property propertyName="certPath" value="/tmp/#[aVariable]/certificate.pem" doc:name="Property"/>
```

I'm now trying to use it inside my sftp outbound-endpoint identityFile attribute, as follows:
identityFile="${certPath}"

This does not work and takes in the placeholder as a string (as is.)

Am I missing something in the way properties should be set and then accessed?

I have also tried to add a message property in the session scope, but then when trying ${session.certPath} nothing gets evaled either.

Comment: What is `<set-property>`? that's not Ant. Is this part of a build file that Ant is executing?

Comment: This is in Mule, you can set a "property" in the XML flow using this construct. You are then supposed to be accessing it using an ant-style notation, but so far I have no luck at figuring out how to actually do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access property  set during a flow you need to use the Mule Expression language.

Try using the following to access your property.

```
#[message.outboundProperties['certPath']]
```

Note: This works only when the property is accessed in the same flow.

The ant style access `${session.certPath}` is for loading properties from properties file.

Refer the following link for more details on MEL.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Property+Transformer+Reference

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know if it works inside the identityFile attribute of the sftp endpoint? From experience none of the mule expressions I've placed there were evaluated at all, but instead taken as strings

Comment: Nope that won't work. Here is what I get:
Message from Processing Engine: Unexpected exception attempting to write file, message was: IdentityFile '#[message.outboundProperties['certPath']]' not found

Comment: The expression is taken as is, as a string, instead of being resolved to the value of that property, or other variable, for that matter.

Comment: The only solution might be to actually create a component that calls the SftpClient class itself with the right file path.